# Is PageFactory class still available in Selenium WebDriver in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, ui-automation

Currently I am learning Selenium WebDriver using C# and I got a lot of issues with it.
I mean I used a lot of resources to learn it but still showing some classes are not exist in Selenium.Support or Selenium.WebDriver.

For example 'PageFactory' class, 'ExpectedConditions' class, [FindsBy] attributes and so on. Am I learning from old sources. If so can you give me some newer documentations for me to learn it. Thank you

Comment: Apparently they decided to get rid of Expected Conditions in the C# bindings.  PageFactory isn't all that useful if the site you are automating uses javascript to update the DOM because the [FindsBy] notations don't use webdriverwaits... but I believe they got rid of that too.   Apparently there are 3rd party nuget packages available to add them back in if you like.  (So yeah, old sources...)

Comment: @pcalkins oh I see. Thank you big for reply, I'd better learn it anyway